# slug value in parent layout in nextjs app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I have the file structure as follows in a NextJS App Router Project.

```
|   |   |   
|   |   +---app
|   |   |   |   page.js
|   |   |   |   layout.js         
|   |   |   \---spaces
|   |   |       |   page.js
|   |   |       |   layout.js
|   |   |       | 
|   |   |       \---[slug]
|   |   |           +---enquiry
|   |   |           |       page.js
|   |   |           \---subscriptions
|   |   |                   page.js
```

I want to retrieve the slug value and use it in `/app/spaces/layout.js`(server component) when a user navigates to `/spaces/10/enquiry` page.

I am able to retrieve and use the slug value in `/app/spaces/[slug]/enquiry/page.js`, but for the layout file in `spaces` folder, the params are always empty.

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of your `layout.js` to retrieve the slug:

```
// /app/spaces/[slug]/enquiry/layout.js

export default function Layout({ children, params }) {
  return (
    <div>{params.slug}</div>
  );
}
```

Read about it in more details: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/layout#params-optional

---

Do note that, the dynamic route parameters object is available from the root segment down to that layout.

Meaning, the `[slug]` wont be available if you try to access it from `app/spaces/layout.js`, but will be available in layouts like:

- `app/spaces/[slug]/layout.js`
- `app/spaces/[slug]/enquiry/layout.js`
- `app/spaces/[slug]/subscriptions/layout.js`